# Is it alright to link a song and ask for it's key?

Tags: support

Here's a link for the song `The Reason` by Hoobastank.

[The Reason by Hoobstank - Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fcvzCfXDsg)

Is it alright to ask for the key in which this song is played? I am a complete beginner and would like to create sheet music for this song.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identification questions are off-topic for the site (see the [FAQ](https://music.stackexchange.com/faq)) but any questions are always welcome in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Well yeah! I wonder how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The recording you linked is in E major.

This question may be of use to you: [What does it mean to write a song in a certain key?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/6445/133)

I would probably have closed as "too localized"--we welcome questions about specific music when it concerns a technique that requires some significant analysis ([for example](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/7241/133)), but this one really doesn't.

Comment: Thanks! The link you have provided is helpful too. It seems like a pretty general method for identifying the key of any song.